# In what way does Firefox and IE treat the image-object diffrent from Webkit?

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a script that adds a class to images, based on if the background-image is landscape or portrait.

Here is the function:

```
function loadImg (mythis, callback) {
    var src = getUrl($(mythis).css('background-image'));


    var t = new Image();
    t.src = src;

    console.log(t.height);

    var height = t.height;
    var width = t.width;
    if(width > height){
        $(mythis).parent().addClass('panorama');    
        $(mythis).parent().parent().removeClass('smallpost');                    

}
```

This great in Webkit, but not in Firefox or IE. The problem is with t.height and t.width, they are always Zero in these browsers. One challenge with this solution is that the images needs to be loaded before the function is run. Because the images are background-images and not in the DOM, I ended up just adding a delay before the script runs. I know it's a bit sinful, but really an acceptable solution in this case. Not sure if that has anything to do with my problems though.

Full javascript:
    $(function(){

```
    setTimeout(function(){
        var elems = $('.post .crop'), count = elems.length;
        $(elems).each(function(i){
            //Rezise image
            loadImg(this, function callback(){

            //Run masonry afte last image
            if (i = count-1){
                $('#content').imagesLoaded(function(){
                    $('#content').masonry({
                        itemSelector : '.post',
                        gutterWidth: 15,
                        columnWidth: 320
                    });
                });
            };



            });
        })
    },5000);

    //getImgSize('http://25.media.tumblr.com/83c73059a904b46afba332f26e33c5bd/tumblr_mmvwy7XjKq1sqsf7io1_500h.jpg')

    function getUrl(styling){
        styling = styling.replace('url(','').replace(')','');
        return (styling);
    }

    function loadImg (mythis, callback) {
        var src = getUrl($(mythis).css('background-image'));


        var t = new Image();
        t.src = src;

        console.log(t.height);

        var height = t.height;
        var width = t.width;
        if(width > height){
            $(mythis).parent().addClass('panorama');    
            $(mythis).parent().parent().removeClass('smallpost');                    

    }

    callback();


    }

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference you see is usually related to caching state of your image : if the image is already available, the dimensions may be immediately known.

You need to handle the `load` event :

```
var t = new Image();
t.onload = function(){
   var height = t.height;
   var width = t.width;
   if(width > height){
       $(mythis).parent().addClass('panorama');    
       $(mythis).parent().parent().removeClass('smallpost');
   }  
};
t.src = src;
```

**EDIT :**

you have another problem in your `getUrl` function : it doesn't remove the quotes that some browsers may add to the style.

Change

```
styling = styling.replace('url(','').replace(')','');
```

to

```
styling = styling.replace('url(','').replace(')','').replace(/"/g,'');
```

Comment: Because sometimes the load event is immediately launched when you set the src and if you set the event handler later it might be to late.

Comment: Did you check the content of src in Firefox ?

Comment: In chrome, the src is rendered in console as a link. In firefox, it's rendered as a url between "". If I console.log t before t.src is declared, i still get an image with a src attribute in chrome. In firefox I get an image without a src attribute. after t.src is set, both images has src-attributes.

Comment: Give us what you have in `$(mythis).css('background-image')` in the different browsers, we'll define a better getUrl function.

Comment: Chrome: url(http://25.media.tumblr.com/3dae9244545eda2849286fc4b9b9ecaf/tumblr_mn2z5vSjee1sqsi8qo5_1280.jpg)

Comment: firefox: url("http://24.media.tumblr.com/f4296cf38101babb8bae14f994ec8630/tumblr_mn6h439Wh91sqsi8qo1_1280.jpg")